# Unable to create a new fossil repo, fossil beginner

Tags: repository, dvcs, fossil

I figured I would check out fossil for some small apps I have to complete. I am not new to DVCS as I have used CVS, subversion, mercurial, and git. After installing on my Mac (10.7), using homebrew, I am left with the following when attempting to run:

```
-> % fossil new ../FOSSIL/project.fossil
fossil: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: abort at 20 in [INSERT INTO user(login,pw,cap,info) VALUES('developer','','dei','Dev');]: column login is not unique
fossil: column login is not unique
INSERT INTO user(login,pw,cap,info) VALUES('anonymous',hex(randomblob(8)),'hmncz','Anon');INSERT INTO user(login,pw,cap,info) VALUES('nobody','','gjor','Nobody');INSERT INTO user(login,pw,cap,info) VALUES('developer','','dei','Dev');INSERT INTO user(login,pw,cap,info) VALUES('reader','','kptw','Reader');

If you have recently updated your fossil executable, you might need to run "fossil all rebuild" to bring the repository schemas up to date.
```

I have attempted to run `fossil init  ../FOSSIL/project.fossil` as well as `fossil clone http://www.fossil-scm.org/ myclone.fossil` which yields the same results as seen above.

I then tried `fossil user list` as it looks like fossil is having issues with logins and users, however fossil expects a repo argument. Searching for the default configuration (something like ~/.gitconfig with git) yielded no results.

I have also tried `rm -rf ~/.fossil` and re-running the above commands as well as using `brew install sqlite` to get the updated version (3.7.7 as of this writing), but neither seem to help.

What do I need to do in order to get fossil functioning properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Silly question... is your own username on the system "developer"? Since that would clash with the name of one of the auto-created users.

Try doing "fossil init -A admin (filename)" to use a different name ("admin" in my example) for the repository owner and see if it works.

Comment: My username is in fact "developer" on this box. Your 'fix' worked as well. The 'error' is misleading in my opinion. Thanks.